# Not displaying any articles on a custom made file

Tags: posts, query-posts, pagination

I have created the file **latest.php** in the public_html so that when I go to **www.domain.com/latest.php** it will show me the latest articles. Sadly, nothing of the posts came up. Later, I will sort them with other ways (mostly based on custom fields).

This is my **latest.php** file (I removed any styling for better understanding)

```
<?php include("wp-load.php"); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

**AND HERE IS WHAT I COPY-PASTED FROM MY INDEX.PHP THAT IS WORKING**

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <a title="" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile; // End the loop ?>

<?php posts_nav_link(' &#183; ', 'previous page', 'next page'); ?>
```

My question is how can I make it possible to show the latest articles with pagination?

Should I use an entire different method for my task? If yes, which one?

UPDATE

header and other functions are working CORRECTLY. It just not shows the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
include ('wp-blog-header.php');
```

and before:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

you have to create wp_query, so do this for example:

```
query_posts('cat=1'); // or any other query args you wish
```

Comment: Thanks, have you found any way to add pagination?

Comment: another syntax for query_posts (using array of args), with paging:
query_posts( array( 'cat' => 1, 'paged' => get_query_var('page') ) );

Answer (score 0):

Your file is completely outside of the Wordpress functionality. In order for this to work, you have to have this inside of a theme under wp-content/themes/your-theme. You will need a stylesheet named style.css (with proper theme definition header) and name this file index.php.

Comment: I do not agree with your answer because having wp-load and wp_head included correctly, I am in the WP functionality. I have created a lot of pages with this exact method, and they are working correctly. This is the first time I needed to show posts. It does display posts but with other post queries, not this one.

Comment: You're right. I missed the wp-load.php line. :) include ('wp-blog-header.php'); is a better solution.

Comment: What is the difference of those two?

Answer (score 0):

try this (relative path)

```
<?php
require( '../my_wordpress_install_root/wp-load.php' );
get_header();
echo 'new content outside WordPress';
get_footer();
?>
```

or fetch feed for your lastest posts

useful link: http://wpengineer.com/1038/embed-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress/

Comment: I call wp-load correctly. It just not showing the posts. Please read again my question